# Wordpress Elementor Plugin Development JavaScript not working in Editor Mode

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, editor, elementor

I'm tryin' to add custom controls to Elementor Editor.
And i want to have a notice which could be closed with jquery.

This is a plugin.php code.

```
<?php

use Elementor\Controls_Manager;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die();

add_action( 'elementor/editor/before_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script' );

function enqueue_my_script() {
    // Enqueue your script for your Elementor addon
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/my-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

class My_Script {

    public static function init() {
        add_action('elementor/documents/register_controls', [__CLASS__, 'add_controls_section'] , 1 , 1 );
    }

    public static function add_controls_section( $element ) {

        $element->start_controls_section(
            'layout_grid-settings',
            [
                'label' => __( 'My Script', 'elementor' ),
                'tab' => Controls_Manager::TAB_SETTINGS,
            ]
        );
        
        $element->add_control(
            'layout_grid_notice',
            [
                'type' => Controls_Manager::RAW_HTML,
                'raw' => '<div id="my-script-notice" class="elementor-panel-alert elementor-panel-alert-info">
                            <p>This feature is available only in Editor Mode</p>
                            <a id="hide-notice" href="#">Got it</a>
                          </div>',
            ]
        );
        
        $element->end_controls_section();
    }
}

My_Script::init();
```

And this is the my-script.js

```
(function($) {
        // Function to hide the notice when the "Got it" link is clicked
        function hideNotice() {
            // Hide the notice
            $('#my-script-notice').hide();
        }

        // Wait for the document to be ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Attach the click event handler to the "Got it" link
            $('#hide-notice').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from navigating
                hideNotice(); // Call the function to hide the notice
            });
        });
    })(jQuery); // Pass in jQuery as the argument to the IIFE
```

Script is loading without any errors, but not working. I've tried it at codepen, it works perfectly. It should work in editor mode with same way as default elementors notices are working. As an example on the fresh install of elementor you can see Favorites Notice which can be closed with "Got It" link.